# Job Market Signaling

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, self-study, bayesian-game, signaling

[image]

My Solution is this

Separating equilibrium

High type worker chooses $e_H = e^* >0$

Low type worker chooses $e_L =0$

Firms believes that if education is $e^* >0$ then the worker is high type and offer wage $= \alpha_H$. If education is zero, then the worker is seen as a low type and offered wage $= \alpha_L$.

For high type worker, utility is $U_H(e) = \alpha_H - \frac{e^*}{2\alpha_H}$.

In order not to deviate H-type to L-type,

$$\alpha_H- \frac{e^*}{2\alpha_H} > \alpha_L - \frac{0}{2\alpha_H} $$

$$\alpha_H- \frac{e^*}{2\alpha_H} > \alpha_L$$

then $e^* < 16$

Similarly, for low type, utility is $U_L(e) = \alpha_L - \frac{0}{2\alpha_L} = \alpha_L$.

In order not to deviate L-type to H-type,

$$\alpha_L > \alpha_H -  \frac{e^*}{2\alpha_L}$$

Then, $e^* >8$

As a result, $8 < e^* < 16$ is a separating equilibrium.

Pooling Equilibrium

Both type workers choose the same education level $e' >0$

Firm believes that high type worker with probability p and low type worker with probability (1-p). Also, we see that $p=1/2$.

So the wage is $w = 1/2 (\alpha_H + \alpha_L)$

For the high type, utility function is $U_H(e) = 1/2(\alpha_H + \alpha_L) - \frac{e'}{2\alpha_H}$

For the high type, utility function is $U_H(e) = 1/2(\alpha_H + \alpha_L) - \frac{e'}{2\alpha_L}$

In oder for high type not to deviate to $e=0$

$$1/2(\alpha_H + \alpha_L) - \frac{e'}{2\alpha_H} > \alpha_L - \frac{0}{\alpha_H}$$

In oder for low type not to deviate to $e=0$

$$ 1/2(\alpha_H + \alpha_L) - \frac{e'}{2\alpha_L}> \alpha_L - \frac{0}{\alpha_H}$$

Then, $e'< 4$

My solution is this. But my solution does not match with the solution manuel. Where is my mistake? I cannot see the mistake. Or what is your solution? Thank you.

Comment: The steps you performed seem correct. However, note that the utility function has $e$ squared. Is the solution $e\in [\sqrt{8},4]$ for separating and $e\in[0,2]$ for pooling?

Comment: As an aside, it is common practice here to type the question instead of just pasting a picture.